# Getting timestamp column and locking in place when a column populates with a new value- Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

I have this interesting request from a user. But I need to put some context. I have this table:

| budget_id | owner | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00002 | brad | Working |
| 00003 | Enrique | Non working |
| NULL | NULL | working |

I already have this conditioned where if the owner or the type are not populated by the user, the budget_id will not populated. The columns owner and type are in a spreadsheet which is manually entered by a user but is imported via a Google Sheet via Big Query).

| budget_id | owner | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00002 | brad | Working |
| 00003 | Enrique | Non working |
| 00004 | Mark | working |

When the user manually input the owner value "Mark", the budget_id will then populate since it satisifies all the necessary conditions. My question: Is it possible via code to know when the budget_id would populate within Big Query and have it as a column? Or this something that would need to be set up via a Big Query DBA to track when the budget_id value is populated?

I'm 50/50 whether this can be done in code or whether I'm venturing into data warehousing at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share how you connect the sheet to BQ (external table, connected sheets)? How do you plan to update the table when user updated the sheet?

Comment: It's through a connected sheet. It will automatically update the table it's connected to.